# NuGet Dotfuscator with Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, dotfuscator

I'm trying run PreEmptive.Protection.Dotfuscator.Pro[.Eval] -Version 6.0.1 in project Xamarin.Android that include Nuget to aid migration from Android Support to Android X:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration">
   <Version>1.0.4</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

but the result is this:

```
"/Droid/Droid.csproj" (default target) (6) ->
(_AndroidXCecilfy target) -> 
   /.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.migration/1.0.4/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(227,9): error : Symbols were found but are not matching the assembly [/Droid/Droid.csproj]
/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.migration/1.0.4/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(227,9): error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadSymbols (Mono.Cecil.Cil.ISymbolReader reader, System.Boolean throwIfSymbolsAreNotMaching) [0x0003c] in <1b16609822914d769fb771c1bb74cd3b>:0  [/Droid/Droid.csproj]
/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.migration/1.0.4/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(227,9): error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00060] in <1b16609822914d769fb771c1bb74cd3b>:0  [/Droid/Droid.csproj]
/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.migration/1.0.4/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(227,9): error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModule (Mono.Cecil.PE.Image image, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00081] in <1b16609822914d769fb771c1bb74cd3b>:0  [/Droid/Droid.csproj]
/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.migration/1.0.4/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(227,9): error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (Mono.Disposable1[T] stream, System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x0000d] in <1b16609822914d769fb771c1bb74cd3b>:0  [/Droid/Droid.csproj]
/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.migration/1.0.4/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(227,9): error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x0006c] in <1b16609822914d769fb771c1bb74cd3b>:0  [/Droid/Droid.csproj]
/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.migration/1.0.4/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(227,9): error :   at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <1b16609822914d769fb771c1bb74cd3b>:0  [/Droid/Droid.csproj]
/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.migration/1.0.4/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(227,9): error :   at Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.CecilMigrator.Migrate (System.String source, System.String destination) [0x001c2] in <865a8af74cb24987acc1eca3a5f0df36>:0  [/Droid/Droid.csproj]
/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.migration/1.0.4/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(227,9): error :   at Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.CecilMigrator.Migrate (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[T] assemblies) [0x00012] in <865a8af74cb24987acc1eca3a5f0df36>:0  [/Droid/Droid.csproj]
/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.migration/1.0.4/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(227,9): error :   at Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.BuildTasks.CecilfyFiles.Execute () [0x000e3] in <770add7f13554ba8ad474c9c8fea5326>:0  [/Droid/Droid.csproj]
```

Information about the build agent OS:

```
=== Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===

Version 8.5.4 (build 12)
Installation UUID: 097d734b-78c4-46b2-a654-ed5233f4a357
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 6.14.1.39 (d16-5 / 30e8706b4)

=== Mono Framework MDK ===

Runtime:
    Mono 6.8.0.123 (2019-10/1d0d939dc30) (64-bit)
    Package version: 608000123

=== .NET Core SDK ===

SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    3.1.200
    2.1.701
    2.1.504
    2.1.302
    2.1.4
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.8.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 10.0.6.2 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d16-3/c407838
Android SDK: /Users/emegonza/Library/Android/sdk
    Supported Android versions:
        6.0 (API level 23)
        8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 30.0.0
SDK Build Tools Version: 30.0.0 rc2

Build Information: 
Mono: mono/mono/2019-06@476d72b9e32
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-3@5836f58
LibZipSharp: grendello/LibZipSharp/d16-3@71f4a94
LibZip: nih-at/libzip/rel-1-5-1@b95cf3fd
ProGuard: xamarin/proguard/master@905836d
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.27.1@8212a2d
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-3@cb41333

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.15.5
Darwin 19.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0
    Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020
```

I run dotfuscator with this lines in the DotfuscatorConfig.xml, to see the error

```
<global>
   <option>verbose</option>
</global>
```

Can you help me to find, why this problem happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Android 9.0 (API level 28) is not a supported Android version. If you read the logs, it says "Supported Android versions: 6.0 (API level 23) 8.1 (API level 27)"

Comment: Please update your nuget package to the latest version and try again. I found some similar issues in Github that may help: [Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadSymbols](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10441) and [Release mode build fails, Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadSymbols error](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/93).

Comment: Hi, I work for PreEmptive, the maker of Dotfuscator. It sounds like you are an Evaluation user or Professional customer, in which I'd encourage you to open a support case (https://www.preemptive.com/contact/supportrequestform) and I'm sure the support team can help you sort this out.